# Matrix from outer product not positive definite

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I was trying to simulate multivariate normal data in python the following way

```
n = 100
p = 10
mu = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=3, size=p)
A = np.random.uniform(low = -4, high = 4, size = (p, 1))
A = pd.DataFrame(A)
Sigma = np.dot(A, np.transpose(A))
Sigma = pd.DataFrame(Sigma)
X = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean = mu, cov = Sigma, size = n)
```

However, the resulting variables are always perfectly linearly correlated. I then checked `np.linalg.eigvals(Sigma)` and realized that `Sigma` is not positive semi-definite. This surprised me since 1) I did not get an error from `multivariate_normal` and 2) `Sigma` was generated from an outer product, which is supposed to be positive semi-definite. Can anyone tell me what's going on and how to fix this?

Comment: `Sigma` looks positive semi-definite to me, when you take account of floating-point issues.  The only negative values I can see are on the order of 1e-15: these really are zeroes with small floating-point rounding issues.

Comment: I suspect the problem for your overall procedure is that `Sigma` has only one non-zero eigenvector and so the "multivariate" distribution is effectively univariate. Heuristically, observe that the `Sigma` you create has fewer degrees of freedom than a real covariance matrix. For example, by construction, `Σ_12 / Σ_11 = Σ_22 / Σ_21 = Σ_32 / Σ_31` because all those ratios are equal to `A[2] / A[1]`. That isn't true of covariance matrices in general.

Comment: [The outer product of a vector with itself has rank 1.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product#Rank_of_an_outer_product)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one idea.  The principle is to generate `p` random vectors (rather than the `p` scalars in the original code), find the covariance between each pair of vectors, then use that covariance matrix to construct the multivariate distribution.  This removes the predictable interrelationships between the elements of the original `Sigma` (see comments).

```
import numpy as np

n = 100
p = 10

mu = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=3, size=p)
A_vec = np.random.uniform(low = -4, high = 4, size = (p, p))
Sigma_vec = np.cov(A_vec)
X = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean = mu, cov = Sigma_vec, size = n)
```

Inspecting the results of this with `np.corrcoef(X.T)` shows that the generated variables are no longer perfectly correlated.